# Run the same codes with data and variable names changed in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I need to run very similar codes for 3 different dataset. My current codes look like this:

```
## data a
a_dat2 <- merge(a_dat, zip, by = "zip", all.x = T)
a_dat2 <- a_dat2 %>%
group_by(zip) %>%
summarize(dist_a_min = min(dist))
## data b
b_dat2 <- merge(b_dat, zip, by = "zip", all.x = T)
    b_dat2 <- b_dat2 %>%
     group_by(zip) %>%
summarize(dist_b_min = min(dist))
## data c
c_dat2 <- merge(c_dat, zip, by = "zip", all.x = T)
    c_dat2 <- c_dat2 %>%
     group_by(zip) %>%
summarize(dist_c_min = min(dist))
```

The codes for the 3 dataset are same except that the name of the data varies: `a_dat`, `b_dat`, `c_dat`. The variable name `dist` varies too: `dist_a_min`, `dist_b_min`, `dist_c_min`. What function/loop can be used to shorten the codes so that I don't need to copy and paste for each dataset separately?

Comment: If the frames are all similar, I recommend storing them in a `list`-of-frames instead of individual frames (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207). From there, you can do `lapply(list_of_frames, function(a) merge(a, zip, by = "zip") %>% ...)` (or `purrr::map`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to place the elements in a `list` with `mget`, loop through the `list` with `imap`, join (`?left_join`) with 'zip' dataset, grouped by 'zip' and get the `min` of 'dist' while creating the column name based on the identifier name substring

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern = "_dat2$")) %>%
        imap(~ left_join(.x, zip, by = 'zip') %>%
             group_by(zip) %>%
             summarise((! str_c('dist_', substr(.y, 1, 1), '_min')  :=  min(dist)))
```

---

Or another option is to create a function for repeated tasks

```
joinSumm <- function(dat, groupName, colName, data2) {
    groupName <- enquo(groupName)
    colName <- enquo(colName)
    nm1 <- str_c('dist_', str_sub(rlang::as_name(enquo(dat)), 1, 1), '_min')
    dat %>%
       left_join(data2, by = rlang::as_name(groupName)) %>%
        group_by(!! groupName) %>%
        summarise((!! nm1) := min(!! colName))

  }
joinSumm(a_dat2, zip, dist, zip)
joinSumm(b_dat2, zip, dist, zip)
```

---

A reproducible example with built-in dataset `iris` (without the join part)

```
list(a_dat = iris, b_dat = iris, c_dat = iris) %>% 
      imap(~ .x %>% 
            group_by(Species) %>%
            summarise(!! str_c('dist_', substr(.y, 1, 1), '_min') := min(Sepal.Length)))
#$a_dat
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    dist_a_min
#  <fct>           <dbl>
#1 setosa            4.3
#2 versicolor        4.9
#3 virginica         4.9

#$b_dat
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    dist_b_min
#  <fct>           <dbl>
#1 setosa            4.3
#2 versicolor        4.9
#3 virginica         4.9

$c_dat
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    dist_c_min
#  <fct>           <dbl>
#1 setosa            4.3
#2 versicolor        4.9
#3 virginica         4.9
```

Comment: awesome as always akrun, great solution

Comment: I used `merge(dat, zip, by = "zip", all.x = T)` in my original codes, so I guess should be `left_join`?